# Meaning of random slope in a glmm? Asking for advice on random effects structure of a generalized linear mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, experiment-design, glmm

I have a categorical DV (right or wrong response to an item = binary) and two categorical IVs, one between-subject IV (condition) with two levels and a within-subject IV (trial) with multiple levels (e.g. 3 tials of 10 items each). We expect some training effects over time that differ between conditions and use a glmm (family = binomial) for analysis. I'm wondering if adding the random slope (condition|item) to the mixed model structure of condition + trial + (1| subject) + (1| item) is reasonable given the experimental design.

Sticking to the advice of [Barr et al. (2013)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0749596X12001180) I tried using the maximal random effects structure that would converge which happens to be with said additional random slope for the IV "condition".
Thinking about this random slope, I'm feeling unsure, what it even means mathmatically (what is exactly being calculated?) and more importantly what this means conceptually (and if that is sensible).
I think, it means, that this model would take into account that, depending on the condition, a partipant's response to each item may differ over time, but I'm probably lacking something.

Additionally, as I'm trying to find the model that describes the data best by doing Likelihood-Ratio-Tests (LRT) on netsted models in R (the random effects only model, models with one IV and a model with both IVs), I might end up with a model including the random slope (condition| item), but not condition as a fixed effect, which I wouldn't know how to properly justify later in a paper.

I'd be very happy about any comment/opinion/advice on how to prodece using LRT to determine which model structure best describes my data and if someone has ever been in a similar situation.

Many thanks for reading my post,
Sahila